# Поиск Range у текста C# Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, interop

Есть некий текст в MS Word, нужен поиск текста, чтобы возвращалось не bool значение, а Range этого текста.

```
document.Content.Find.Execute(findText) // возвращает bool. Нашел этот текст или нет. Как можно найти Range этого текста?
```

Comment: [Программный поиск и замена текста в документах](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-and-replace-text-in-documents?view=vs-2019) - оно?

Comment: Да, я там нашел, как найти Range. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось все просто. Нужно сперва выделить найденный текст через Selection, а потом получить его Range.

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = application.Documents.Open(pathFile);
string findText = "Текст";
    application.Selection.Find.Execute(findText);
var FindRange = application.Selection.Range;
```